# Grouping list elements based on values in list

Tags: list, prolog, tuples, grouping

i have a list of elements(tuples):

```
tuples(
        [
            (a,b,[1,3,5,7]),
            (a,b,[9,11,13,15]),
            (a,b,[17,19,21,23]),
            (c,d,[0,2,4,6]),
            (c,d,[8,10,12,14]),
            (c,d,[16,18,20,22]),
            (e,f,[100,200,300,400]),
            (e,f,[500,600,700,800]),
            (e,f,[900,1000,1100,1200])
        ]
    ).
```

How to group them so it becomes:

```
[
        (a,b,[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23]),
        (c,d,[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22]),
        (e,f,[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200])
]
```

As we can see, we grouped the `(a,b) (c,d) (e,f)` and concatenated their respective lists.

thank you for the help.

Comment: would you like to solve it by coding a recursive solution? have you tried that? what was the difficulty?

Comment: Break up this deep & nasty (uses conjunction `(_,_)` inside) datastructure using extractor predicates: `some_tuple(V,W,Values) :- tuples(Tuples), member((V,W,Values), Tuples).` Then proceed from there.

Comment: SWI-Prolog has [group_by/4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=group_by/4) [Examples](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/group-by-4-examples/2678)

Answer (score 2):

How about this somewhat SQL-ish way:

**Step 1**

Define a predicate to access data in the original (deep and nasty) data structure. Note that this datastructure actually uses conjunction `(_,_,_) = (_,(_,_))` to create what looks like triples, one should properly use list construction throughout: `[a,b,[1,3,5,7]]`.

```
some_tuple(V,W,List) :- 
   tuples(Tuples), 
   member((V,W,List), Tuples).
```

On backtracking, `some_tuple/3` will pull out the individual
records one by one and present the information therein in the head variables:

```
?- some_tuple(V,W,List).

List = [1, 3, 5, 7],
V = a,
W = b ;
List = [9, 11, 13, 15],
V = a,
W = b ;
...
```

**Step 2**

Collect all the lists for a given (`V`,`W`) pair using [bagof/3](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3), followed by list flattening:

```
flat_list(V,W,FlatList) :-
   bagof(List,some_tuple(V,W,List),BagOfListsForVW),
   flatten(BagOfListsForVW,FlatList).
```

We get:

```
?- flat_list(V,W,FlatList).

FlatList = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23],
V = a,
W = b ;
FlatList = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22],
V = c,
W = d ;
FlatList = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200],
V = e,
W = f.
```

**Step 3**

Collect all the solutions found by `flat_list/3` into one final list to obtain the desired result.

```
solution(FinalBag) :-
   bagof(
      (V,W,ResultList), % use conjunction instead of [V,W,RL] 
      flat_list(V,W,ResultList),
      FinalBag
   ).
```

And so:

```
solution(FinalBag).

FinalBag = [
   (a,b,[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23]),
   (c,d,[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]), 
   (e,f,[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200])
].
```

If you are in SWI-Prolog, you may have to tell the toplevel printer to not elide long lists:

```
?-
set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options,[max_depth(100)]).
```

Comment: had the feeling something like this could be done, went the simplified route instead.... :) also, you can use `append` instead of `flatten`.

Comment: @WillNess Once you have the "extraction predicate" in front of you, things somehow automatically grow together.

Comment: (edited) isn't it the *inner* `bagof` that does the backtracking? also you have a typo, it's supposed to be `BagForVW` instead of `SubBag` (or vice versa).

Comment: @WillNess You are right! Also, the typo comes from making the code clearer w/o testing it afterwards. Sorry..

Comment: What does `SubBag^` do in this code? (That doesn't seem to be a variable used anywhere else)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler (Much later...) You are right. Sorry for the mess. Fixed. This was bad.

Answer (score 2):

A variation using [foldl](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4)/4 and then library([yall](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)):

```erlang
'Grouping list elements based on values in list'(Gs) :-
    tuples(Ts),
    foldl([(X,Y,L),V0,V1]>>(
              (  append(N,[(X,Y,L0)|M],V0)
              -> append(L0,L,L1)
              ;  N=V0, L1=L
              ),
              append(N,[(X,Y,L1)|M],V1)
          )
          ,Ts,[],Gs).
```

*a day after...*

There is a bug going unnoticed, namely *M* remains unbound where a pair of keys (that is, *X,Y* in a tuple) is not present in *V0* (have attempted to keep the variables naming coherent to the docs for foldl/4). A possible correction, that illustrates a single unification call ([=](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D)/2)/2) to perform multiple 'assignments' at once:

```erlang
    ...
    foldl([(X,Y,L),V0,V1]>>(
              (  append(N,[(X,Y,L0)|M],V0)
              -> append(L0,L,L1)
              ;  (N,M,L1)=(V0,[],L1)
              ),
              append(N,[(X,Y,L1)|M],V1)
    ...
```

Still, it's not clear to me why the bug didn't materialized... for instance, here it's clearly visible...

```erlang
?- append([1,2,3],[4,5,6|_],R).
R = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6|_19156].
```

*another way...*

library([solution_sequences](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences)) is a recent addition to SWI-Prolog arsenal, providing more 'SQL like' constructs, for instance [group_by](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=group_by/4)/4:

```erlang
by_group_by(Gs) :-
    tuples(Ts),
    findall((X,Y,All_xy), (
      group_by([X,Y],L,member((X,Y,L),Ts),Lt),
      append(Lt,All_xy)
    ),Gs).
```

The documentation is too much terse, but overall, the library is worth a try. There are some [examples](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/group-by-4-examples/2678) posted in SWI-Prolog discourse group, but I find the data used there boring and difficult to understand.

Note: I used the syntax [X,Y] for the free variables, to make clear the 'shape' of this important specification is *unrelated* to the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
group([],L,L).
group([(A,B,L)|T],Acc,Out):-
    (   append(L1,[(A,B,LL)|L2], Acc)
    ->  append(LL,L,LLL),
        append(L1,[(A,B,LLL)|L2], NewAcc),
        group(T,NewAcc,Out)
    ;   append(Acc,[(A,B,L)],NewAcc),
        group(T,NewAcc,Out)
    ).

?- tuples(L), group(L,[],G).
G = [
     (a,b,[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23]),
     (c,d,[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]), 
     (e,f,[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200])
    ],
L = [
     (a,b,[1, 3, 5, 7]), 
     (a,b,[9, 11, 13, 15]),  
     (a,b,[17, 19, 21, 23]), 
     (c,d,[0, 2, 4, 6]),  
     (c,d,[8, 10, 12, 14]),  
     (c,d,[16, 18, 20, 22]),   
     (e,f,[100, 200, 300, 400]),  
     (e,f,[500, 600, 700, 800]),  
     (e,f,[900, 1000, 1100, 1200])
    ].
```

Basically I'm stripping an element from the (tuple) list (`[(A,B,L)|T]`) and look if I got a similar entry within my bag-list (2nd argument, `append(L1,[(A,B,LL)|L2]`, Acc)). I use `append/3` to do so because it can be used to find an element and at the same time dividing the original list into the list before and after the found element.
If I found an entry in the baglist, I append the two number lists (`L` and `LL`) to a new one (`LLL`) and exchange the values within the bag-list. Then I call the predicate again with the rest list and the altered bag-list.
If no element fits, I just add the element to the bag-list (as last element, `append(Acc,[(A,B,L)],Acc2)`) and call the predicate again. So each time I call the predicate `group/3` it's first argument loses an element. Until there is no element left `(group([],L,L).`), in this case I state my bag-list is my ouput.

After playing a bit around with `group_by/4` and/or `bagof/3` as suggested by Guy coder, and using a variant of Davids "extraction" predicate here is another solution:

```
one_tuple(V,W,Value) :- 
   tuples(Tuples), 
   member((V,W,Values), Tuples),
   member(Value, Values).

?- findall((A,B,Cs), bagof(C, one_tuple(A, B, C), Cs), O).
O = [(a,b,[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23]),
     (c,d,[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22]),
     (e,f,[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200])].
```

Comment: See comment in question for suggesting to use group_by/4.

Comment: @GuyCoder nice :)

Comment: @Raubsauger I hope your are planning to sleep.  As your [bio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8080648/raubsauger) notes, there seems to be something wrong on the Internet. In other words, where is the update using group_by/4 ?   :)

Comment: @GuyCoder I'll update my profile just for you.

Comment: That was not the preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to be able to find the list of unique `A,B` pairings in the list of tuples:

```
foo(X,A,B) :-
    setof( p(A,B), C^member( (A,B,C), X ), T), 
    member( p(A,B), T).

/* 48 ?- tuples(_X), foo(_X,A,B).
A = a,
B = b ;
A = c,
B = d ;
A = e,
B = f. */
```

Next we collect the tuples for each pair of the `A` and `B` values:

```cpp
bar(X,A,B,G) :- 
    foo(X,A,B),      % for each unique (A,B,_) in X
    findall( C,      % find all Cs such that (A,B,C) is in X
               member( (A,B,C), X),
             CS),
    append( CS,G).   % and append them together
    
/* 66 ?- tuples(_X), bar(_X,A,B,G).
A = a,
B = b,
G = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23] ;
A = c,
B = d,
G = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22] ;
A = e,
B = f,
G = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200].*/
```

So that the grouping is done with

```cpp
groups(X,GS):-
    findall( (A,B,G),  bar(X,A,B,G),  GS).

/* 68 ?- tuples(_X), groups(_X, GS).
GS = [(a, b, [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23]), 
      (c, d, [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]), 
      (e, f, [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 
              900, 1000, 1100, 1200])]. 
*/
```

---

*update:* from [David Tonhofer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884463/david-tonhofer)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65135188/849891), we see that it can be done with just one nested  `bagof` call,

```ml
solution( Sol ) :-
   tuples(TS),
   bagof( (A,B,FLS),     % (* collect (A,B,FLS) for each (A,B) *)
          LS^(           % (* such that (A,B,L) is in TS       *)
                bagof( L,  member((A,B,L), TS),  LS ),
                flatten( LS, FLS)
             ),          % (* with the lists LS flattened      *)
          Sol ).
```

The outer `bagof`'s goal predicate (i.e. the inner `bagof` call) is automatically backtracking to produce its `LS` result for each *distinct* pair of the `A,B` values, automagically achieving the same effect as we had "manually", in this answer.